# Unable to Graph Data in Grafana from Clickhouse Datasource

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I am new to Grafana. The data I am trying to plot shows fine in tabular format but when I try to visualize using Graph, it shows Unable to graph data.

The tabular data is as follows:

```
count()     t
----------------------------
54       2020-12-02 09:00:00
387      2020-12-02 09:01:00
1462     2020-12-02 09:02:00
```

and this is the query:

```
SELECT
    count(),
    $dateTimeCol as t
FROM $table
where date='2020-12-02'
GROUP BY t

ORDER BY t
```

I am using Grafana/7.1.4 and [clickhouse](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource) as datasource. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be used [$timeSeries](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource)-macros:

```sql
SELECT
    $timeSeries t,
    count()
FROM $table
WHERE date='2020-12-02' /* should be used 'WHERE $timeFilter' ? */
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t
```

---

Let's emulate test dataset:

```sql
SELECT
    $timeSeries as t,
    count()
FROM (select (now() - rand() % 24*60*60) AS dt from $table limit 1024)
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t
```

define Query params - *FROM* as *system.numbers*, *Column:DateTime* as *dt*:

[image: Grafana query panel]

and for 24h range get graph:

[image: Grafana graph]