# How to write SQL to make the panel get data from Clickhouse?

Tags: sql, performance, prometheus, grafana, clickhouse

[image]

---

clickhouse table struct:

```
┌─name──────────┬─type──────────┬
│ FieldUUID     │ UUID          │
│ EventDate     │ Date          │
│ EventDateTime │ DateTime      │
│ Metric        │ String        │
│ LabelNames    │ Array(String) │
│ LabelValues   │ Array(String) │
│ Value         │ Float64       │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴
```

Row 1:

---

```
FieldUUID:     7dcd9485-bf32-4b1f-a5cc-4a9f41bcecd8
EventDate:     2021-05-14
EventDateTime: 2021-05-14 18:50:41
Metric:        yarn_app
LabelNames:    ['id','queue']
LabelValues:   ['application_1616183484052_0240','root.users.spark.u12']
Value:         349755813888
```

---

Can't find relevant instance:

- https://clickhouse.tech/docs/zh/sql-reference/statements/select/
- https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource/
- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/2515

**question:**

How the grafana panel gets data from Clickhouse?

Comment: Are your query returning the result in clickhouse-client ? Because in your pre where clause metric value not matching with you Row 1 data.

Comment: It should be used [$timeSeries and $timeFilter](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource)-macroses - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65419185/303298

Comment: Confirm whether the data exists through the Clickhouse-client. The data exists, which can be known through clickhouse-client @SounakSaha

Comment: How to write sql? Achieve this effect: `name{label1="value1",label2="value2"} value` @vladimir

Comment: Look to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662019/1204665