# Is this the correct way to use it via grafana?

Tags: sql, performance, prometheus, grafana, clickhouse

---

**ClickHouse:**

```
┌─name──────────┬─type──────────┬
│ FieldUUID     │ UUID          │
│ EventDate     │ Date          │
│ EventDateTime │ DateTime      │
│ Metric        │ String        │
│ LabelNames    │ Array(String) │
│ LabelValues   │ Array(String) │
│ Value         │ Float64       │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴
```

```
Row 1:
──────
FieldUUID:     499ca963-2bd4-4c94-bc60-e60757ccaf6b
EventDate:     2021-05-13
EventDateTime: 2021-05-13 09:24:18
Metric:        cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used
LabelNames:    ['host']
LabelValues:   ['test01']
Value:         104189952
```

---

**Grafana:**

```sql
SELECT
        EventDateTime,
        Value AS cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used
    FROM
        $table
    WHERE
        Metric = 'cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used'
        AND $timeFilter 
    ORDER BY
        EventDateTime
```

no data points.

**question:** Is this the correct way to use it via grafana?

Example:
cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used{host='test01'} 104189952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana expects your SQL will return time series data format for most of the visualization.

- One column `DateTime\Date\DateTime64 or UInt32` which describe
  timestamp
- One or several columns with Numeric types (Float, Int*,
  UInt*) with metric values (column name will use as time series name)
- optional one column with String which can describe multiple time
  series name

or advanced "time series" format, when first column will `timestamp`, and the second column will `Array(tuple(String, Numeric))` where `String` column will time series name (usually it used with

so, select table `metrics.shell` as table and `EventDateTime` as field in drop-down in `query editor` your query could be changed to

```
    SELECT
        EventDateTime,
        Value AS cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used
    FROM
        $table
    WHERE
        Metric = 'cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used'
        AND $timeFilter 
    ORDER BY
        EventDateTime
```

SQL query from your post, can be visualized without changes only with the `Table` plugin and you shall change "time series" to "table" format for properly data transformation on grafana side

Comment: could you share your "Generated SQL" from query editor?

Comment: I have been working hard for a week, but I can't solve it. It seems I can't solve it by myself. @Slach

Comment: i ask you again please share your "Generated SQL" from grafana clickhouse query editor

Comment: [Generated SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGSz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Analog for promQL query
`cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used{host='test01'} 104189952`
should look like

```sql
SELECT
        EventDateTime,
        Value AS cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used
    FROM
        $table
    WHERE
        Metric = 'cluster_cm_agent_physical_memory_used'
        AND LabelValues[indexOf(LabelNames,'host')] = 'test01'
        AND $timeFilter 
    ORDER BY
        EventDateTime
```

Comment: [Generated SQL image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGSz.png)  If I replace $timeFilter with EventDateTime = '2021-05-26 09:10:29', I can get the data, but there is no time series.

Comment: what time series do you expect when you setup only one second? 
could you try run generated SQL inside into clickhouse-client and check which data is returned

Comment: Yes, I set one second because `$timeFilter` returns no data points.

Comment: I found the reason: Time of the latest data in Clickhouse: `EventDateTime: 2021-05-27 06:56:01`, Time of the latest data in generated SQL: `1622076908 (2021-05-27 08:55:08)`

Comment: check your ingestion process
maybe you lost timezone when try to insert data into clickhouse?

Comment: **yes** exactly